# Tkinter Button loop - How to create a loop with multiple buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

As you can see in my code, I am in the process of creating buttons that should alternate with black and white. However, if the user clicks on one of these buttons, the respective coordinates should be output. My goal is to output an 8x8 field, where each field or button alternates with the color from black to white (like a chessboard) and you can query the coordinates of each field. I've already tried a few attempts with for loops, but without success. Since I don't want to create 64 different buttons, there must be some way to loop this around. Can someone give me a few tips or suggestions on how I could solve this problem?

Here is my Code:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')

def btn_1(event):
    print("00")

button1 = Button(window, width=10, height=4, bg='black')
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", btn_1)

def btn_2(event):
    print("01")

button2 = Button(window, width=10, height=4, bg='white')
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2.bind("<Button-1>", btn_2)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def coordinates(x,y):
    print(x,y)

for i in range(8):
    if i%2==0:
        
        for k in range(8):
            if k%2 ==0:
                tk.Button(root,bg="black",command=lambda x=i,y=k: coordinates(x,y)).grid(row=i,column=k)
            else:
                tk.Button(root,bg="white",command=lambda x=i,y=k: coordinates(x,y)).grid(row=i,column=k)
    else:
        for k in range(8):
            if k%2 ==0:
                tk.Button(root,bg="white",command=lambda x=i,y=k: coordinates(x,y)).grid(row=i,column=k)
            else:
                tk.Button(root,bg="black",command=lambda x=i,y=k: coordinates(x,y)).grid(row=i,column=k)
```

This code block creates a 8x8 chessboard like field. You can specify the button parameters. I only specified colors since it is an example.

Comment: This one looks pretty good. But do you know, how I can coordinate the buttons? For example 00, 01,...

Comment: Why do you need to "coordinate" them?  Is the reason to know which button was clicked when user clicks a button?

Comment: My teacher gave me the task, that I need to coordinate these buttons. Every time the user press one of these buttons, he should know what the position of this button is. That means, if I press a button in the 4th row / 3rd column, for example, it should contain '32' as the answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now, it does both of what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I love you, you're the best! But can you explain me how those for loops work?

Comment: First for loop I created is for rows and since you want to create 8 rows, I created it using "range(8)". Then, I added an if statement because in a chessboard one row starts with black tile another one startswith white tile. Rows that are multiples of 2 will start with a black tile and rows that are not multiples of 2 will start with a white tile.


Now, We've created the rows but we need to create 8 tiles in that row. Thus, we need another for loop. We'll again create the for loop with "range(8)" since we need 8 tiles.
Sınce we want alternating tiles we again implement an if statement.

Comment: and what does this lambda function do and the other following statements after that?

Answer (score 0):

While binding the buttons add a lambda as the function.

For example:

```
def click(x, y):
    print(str(x) + str(y))

for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        if ((x+1) * (y+1)) % 2 == 0:
            button = tk.Button(root, bg='white').grid(row=x, column=y)
        else:
            button = tk.Button(root, bg='white').grid(row=x, column=y)
        
        button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x=x, y=y: click(x, y))
```

The click function will be called and the button's coordinates will be passed as the x and y arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the values needed with relatively simple math operations to accomplish what you need (and the built-in [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function to make it slightly faster). This also allows making the code more "data-driven" by avoiding the need to hardcode numerical values in as many places.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 8, 8
GRID_SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT
COLORS = 'black', 'white'

def callback(row, col):
    print(f'{row}{col}')

for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
    row, col = divmod(i, WIDTH)
    offset = row % 2
    color = COLORS[(i+offset) % 2]
    btn = tk.Button(window, width=10, height=4, bg=color,
                    command=lambda row=row, col=col: callback(row, col))
    btn.grid(row=row, column=col)

window.mainloop()
```